# Devops deployment to D1 Shared Infrastructure app being ignored

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a PHP Azure web app and I am deploying to it with a Dev Ops release. If is a D1 Shared Infrastructure app service plan.

I have done a build and a release that appear to work fine and everything looks successful. But the old site is still present and if I look at the files on the web app they are all dated for the previous release. So it's as though the release never happened and it disappeared into the void. I have restarted the site several times, to no avail. I have deployed the same build to other web apps and it works fine. All the app settings look the same as the sites where it does work.

I'm tempted to try scaling up at least temporarily to an S1. Not tried that yet, but is there another way?

Comment: How did you deploy the PHP application to Azure app service? Could you please share the release definition settings and the complete logs (enable the variable `system.debug`)?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, please make sure you have really deployed the app to D1, just enable the variable `system.debug` (set the value to `true`), then trigger a new release to capture and check the complete logs.

Generally, it will update the changed files to the site. However you can also try to delete all the destination files before deploying. Just try the following things:

- If you are using `Azure App Service Deploy task` to deploy it, then
  you can enable the additional option to `Remove Additional Files at Destination`.
  [image]
- Besides, you can also try the extenion [Azure WebApp Virtual File
  System Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geertvdcruijsen.GeertvanderCruijsen-Vsts-Release-AzureWebAppVFS), it can delete files from Azure Web Apps through
  KUDU Virtual File System Rest API (Put & Get coming soon)
- If that still not work, then you can write a script to delete the
  specific folder. But you need to make sure that the service account
  has the correct permission to access and delete the folder on Azure.

Alternately you can Remove-Item with Specific Credential, below script for example:

```
Param(
  [string]$computerName = "computername",
  [string]$path ="E:\test\specific-folder"
)
$Username = "domain\user"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$password)

Invoke-Command -computername $computerName {Remove-Item -path $args[0] -Recurse} -cred $cred
```

Comment: I added the system.debug setting and all the files disappeared. In the end I just deleted the app and recreated it in the same D1. The release worked fine with a new web app.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved the issue, you can freely accept the answer if it helps.